# Аттория [значение слова]

Tags: значение-слов

Что подразумевает? Как понимаю слово из итальянского языка, попытался найти ответ в гуглере, но без толку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Аттория = атторней [англ, attorney] - в англоязычных странах - доверенный представитель, оказывающий юридические услуги какому-л. лицу или компании; должностное лицо, которое выполняет функции обвинителя или защитника; генеральный а. (а. -генерал) - в Англии и нек-рых других государствах - член правительства, выступающий от имени государства в судебных делах; в США - глава министерства юстиции, генеральный прокурор.

Информация по завершенному расследованию должна предоставляться по запросу Атторией США или назначенного им представителя или соответствующего чиновника Министерства юстиции.